# Flutter Localizations returns wrong Locale country on Android Emulator

Tags: flutter

I have configured my location on Extended Controls of Android Emulator for Portugal and running Google Maps on that emulator confirms my current location for Portugal as shown on next images (also my Windows settings region is for Portugal). Yet, running my Flutter App always returns US with the following code:

```dart
final country1 = Localizations.localeOf(context).countryCode; // US
final country2 = WidgetsBinding.instance?.window.locale.countryCode; // US
```

What am I missing?

[image: android settings]
[image: google maps location]
[image: window settings region]
[image: flutter locale at runtime]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you declared the variable with the final keyword and it can't change its value from the default value (US)

From:

```
final country = Localizations.localeOf(context).countryCode;
```

To:

```
country = Localizations.localeOf(context).countryCode;
```